# What's wrong with java.util.Stack?

Tags: java

Initializing a basic stack with `Stack s = new Stack()` doesn't have actual methods in it? No `push` or `pop` methods exist?

Following this basic [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_stack_class.htm), error message says `The method push(Integer) is undefined for the type Stack`.
e.g. a basic operation like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackOfPlates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack s = new Stack();
        s.push(new Integer(6));
    }
}
```

Throws undefined function errors.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: the same piece of code runs fine for me, what java version are you using?

Comment: according to `java -version` I'm using `1.8.0_112`, but Oracle documentation indicates that it has existed since 1.0. I've no idea whats going on rn.

Comment: What's wrong with your code or your compiler, you mean. Compilation errors are printed, not thrown.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would probably use a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) like [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), and don't use *raw types*.

```
Deque<Integer> s = new ArrayDeque<>();
s.push(1);
s.push(2);
s.stream().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Which outputs 2 then 1.

If you change it to use a [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), it's the same fundamental issue - don't use raw types. It should look something like,

```
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();
s.push(1);
s.push(2);
s.stream().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

which gives the same but in reverse.

Comment: Using raw types should throw an undefined error? Also, the shared piece of code works fine for me, what could possibly throw an error there?

Comment: yes that obviously fixes the problem but I should still be able to use raw types.

Comment: Also, mine is not letting me definte generic types. It tells me to change something like `Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>()` to `Stack s = new Stack()`

Comment: Oops, sorry guys. I defined a class called `Stack` eariler in the package but forgot to delete it. Sorry for the basic mistake.

Comment: All that while I was wondering what that `*` in imports was doing.